# Differentiability at a point $(0,0)$

Tags: derivatives

How would i show $$\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: i've considered showing its not continuous and using linear approximation and showing the limit is different by paramaterising, and nothing seems to work

Comment: $f(x)$ Differentiable $\implies$ $f(x)$ Continuous, but $f(x)$ Continuous $\not\implies$ $f(x)$ Differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean to set $f(0,0) = 0$. In that case, the function most definitely *is* continuous, so trying to show it's not won't work :)

If it were differentiable, the derivative would have to be given by the matrix
$$Df(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)\end{bmatrix}.$$
Both these partial derivatives are $0$ (note that $f(x,0) = f(0,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)$). On the other hand, if we try to compute the directional derivative in the direction of the vector $\mathbf v=(2,1)$ we obtain
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(2t,t)-f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{6t^4}{t|t|^3},$$
which might look like $6$, but in fact does not exist.

**Caveat**: I do not know what sort of course you're taking. In some courses, directional derivatives require unit vectors; in other courses, they do not. Either way, it doesn't matter here.

But it's a basic **Theorem** that *if* $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ we can compute the directional derivative at in direction $\mathbf v$ by taking $Df(0,0)\mathbf v$, which in this case would be $0$ for all vectors $\mathbf v$.

Thus, $f$ cannot be differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: i dont fully understand how, from this, you've concluded that f cannot be differentiable at the point

Comment: I'm using the contrapositive of the Theorem I stated: If it *were* differentiable, then every directional derivative would exist and would equal $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in spherical coordinates by setting $x=r \cos(\phi)$ and  $y=r \sin(\phi)$. Then the expression is equal to
$$\frac{1}{4}r \sin(4\phi)$$

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

f will be differentiable at (0,0) $\iff$

$\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f_{x}(0,0)h-f_{y}(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$.

Since $f_{x}(0,0)=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$, we need to show that

$\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{hk(h^2-k^2)}{(h^2+k^2)^2}\ne0$; and

this can be done by considering the limit along the line $h=2k$, say, or by using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be plotted like this:

[image: z(x,y)]
I plotted it by entering `((x)*y*(x*x - y*y))/((x*x + y*y)^(3/2)) + 4` to [this](http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/) website.

I would shift the function up or down $g(x,y) = f(x, y) + k)$. After that, proving $g(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(k,k)$ is same as proving that $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.